# How do I create a div that expands with more information upon mouseover (with a background image?

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-animate, expand

I would like to create a div that expands to two paragraphs when someone mouses over the first paragraph.  The first paragraph would be an introduction.  The second paragraph would explain a bit more and may contain a link to another page.  I would like the second paragraph to be hidden until the person moused over the introductory paragraph. I have a background image which looks like a Post-it note.

My attempts at this are here:  http://jsfiddle.net/sAW2c/52/.  The second paragraph isn't hidden, even though I constrained the size of the div and the padding on the P isn't working either.  Can someone head me in the correct direction?

Comment: Please use non-inline styles next time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `#div1` seems to fix the issue: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/pdcvz/).

**Note:** Please use jsFiddle's CSS tab for styles next time. Inline styles are generically not very preferable.

Comment: I did that so people could see what I was doing:-))  I will use the right tab next time.

Comment: @user1658270 Note: when one of the answers to your questions resolves your issue, click the tick next to it to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @user1658270 Here's how it should be done for `.div1` for instance: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/uBhJx/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding overflow hidden to the div should help. Check out this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sAW2c/53/)**. You should get the basic idea here but you'll need to tweak your background and text padding.

**jQuery**

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '300px'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '100px'
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" style="height:120px; width:206px;overflow:hidden;background: url('http://quiltersbee.com/images/white-postit.png') no-repeat 0 0; ">
    <p style="padding-left: 8;padding-right: 8;">This is the paragraph that I would like to be only 190px wide and placed on the background image.  It should be left-aligned. </p><br />
    <p style="padding-left: 8;padding-right: 8;">This is the paragraph I would like to hide until someone mousesovers the above paragraph.  Both paragraphs should be indented so they don't overlap the shading on the background image when this paragraph shows.  This paragraph may include a link.</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: I am still a little lost.  I couldn't seem to put this in a web page and get it to work.  I surrounded the jQuery with script tags in the head and later in the body but neither option worked.  I know I am missing something obvious, but what is it?

Comment: Put the code above inside this in the head of your page `<script> $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });</script>`